# WPF JpegBitmapDecoder creating different height and width

Tags: .net, wpf, image, image-processing, jpeg

I'm attempting to read in a Jpeg image and bind it to a rectangle's fill property with the following code:

```
Dim filePath as string = "PathToJpeg.jpg"     
Dim imageStreamSource As New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
Dim decoder As New JpegBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default)
Dim bitmapSource As BitmapSource = decoder.Frames(0)
```

When I read this in with smaller images, this works ok. But when I point it to a graphic that's 3840 by 3024, `bitmmapSource.Height` reads 924 and `bitmapSource.Width` reads 1174

From what I can tell, it's almost like 1024x768 is the upper limit

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: I believe your sorce jpeg is received from the scanner (~300DPI)? 
In this case the results are quite expectable, because the BitmapSource.Width property gets the width of the bitmap in device-independent units (1/96th inch per unit). Please, try the BitmapSource.PixelWidth/BitmapSource.DpiX properties...

Comment: @Saint Domino: in reference to your bounty comment, are you saying that you think loading a JPEG directly into a Bitmap is a hack whereas using JpegBitmapDecoder is not a hack? I would probably think the opposite.

Comment: Yes. My end goal here is to load a jpeg from the file system and use it as the fill of a WPF rectangle, retaining the original height and width. I *shouldn't* have to resort to GDI+ (and add the system.drawing assembly) in order to do this. I *can* utilize a System.Drawing.Bitmap... but for this scenario, I shouldn't have to. That is why I think it's a hack.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really know why you are using a JpegBitmapDecoder explicitly. My C# code for this is pretty simple:

```
BitmapSource bitmapSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"PathToJpeg.jpg"));
```

The BitmapSource class offers two width and height properties:

Width: Gets the width of the bitmap in device-independent units (1/96th inch per unit). ([From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.MEDIA.IMAGING.BITMAPSOURCE.WIDTH%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true))

PixelWidth: Gets the width of the bitmap in pixels.([From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.pixelwidth.aspx))

I tested this with a 111 MPixel image and it works fine.